# Show Dynamic GoogleMap Marker from JSON

Tags: swift, google-maps, cllocationmanager

How can i show the **dynamic markers** in Google Map Marker from after **fetching response of Latitude and Longitude from JSON** here is my show marker code but i init camera object in viewDidLoad() so it's not working but if didn't init camera object in viewDidLoad() the camera object shows error

here is the showMarkerFunction:

```
private func showMarker(_ lat: String, _ lng: String, _ description: String){

        let latitude: CLLocationDegrees = Double(lat) ?? 0.00
        let longitude: CLLocationDegrees = Double(lng) ?? 0.00

        print("Latitude: \(latitude), Longitude: \(longitude)")


        let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
        marker.title = ""
        marker.map = self.mapView

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly, set the camera in loadView method like that

```
override func loadView() {

    // set mapView with settings
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 30.101932, longitude: 31.379173, zoom: 15.5)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: .zero, camera: camera)
    mapView.delegate = self
    mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    mapView.settings.compassButton = true
    mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
    mapView.setMinZoom(8, maxZoom: 20)
    self.mapView = mapView
    view = mapView
}
```

then set marker function like that

```
func drawMarker(lat: CLLocationDegrees , long: CLLocationDegrees, description : String) {
    let marker = GMSMarker()
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
    marker.icon = UIImage(named: "")
    marker.map = mapView
}
```

finally in viewDidLoad function call your method

```
drawMarker(lat: Double("your value"), long: Double("your value"), description: "")
```

Comment: my question is that after the json parse i got all the latitude and longitude not in viewDidLoad or loadView ...

Comment: how can i achieve this goal after json parse in response closure i can drop the pins

Comment: ok you can call this method in any place you want, let say if your callback object form your JSON parse is branches object array then you can implement that         for branch in branches {
            drawMarker(lat: Double(branch.lat)!, long: Double(branch.lng)!, branchInfo: branch)
        }

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your logic please if possible do update code i am very thankful